# Combining Spark schema without duplicates using PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

unable to combine the following three to a single final schema without duplicate columns.
**Here is the code below:**

```
schema1 = StructType([StructField("A", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("B", StringType(), True)])
schema2 = StructType([StructField("c", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("B", StringType(), True)])
schema3 = StructType([StructField("D", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("A", StringType(), True)])
final=(schema1 ++ schema2 ++ schema3).distinct
print( final)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
schema1 = StructType([StructField("A", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("B", StringType(), True)])
schema2 = StructType([StructField("c", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("B", StringType(), True)])
schema3 = StructType([StructField("D", StringType(), True),
                        StructField("A", StringType(), True)])
final = StructType(list(set(schema1.fields+schema2.fields+schema3.fields)))
print(final)
```

gives

```
StructType(List(StructField(B,StringType,true),StructField(D,StringType,true),StructField(c,StringType,true),StructField(A,StringType,true)))
```